# Python reading text file not working with numpy/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to read a text file into Python but I can't seem to do it. If I use `np.loadtxt('file')`, I get a URL error (not sure why...). If I use pandas it doesn't seem to parse the columns correctly. It looks like this:

```
   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00
  -3.6344707e-03  -2.6598413e-02   8.4534688e-02  -8.6057356e-04   3.4833275e-04  -1.7481226e-05
  -7.6545137e-03  -6.9117133e-02   1.0195991e-02  -1.1818548e-03   6.2261736e-04  -1.1414899e-04
```

I'm sure part of the issue is because the delimiter is 3 spaces but I can't seem to solve this.

Pandas would also be an acceptable alternative...

Comment: `loadtxt` shouldn't a problem with that file - provided you provide the right file name!  If there was `url` error, that means there was some problem accessing the file, by name or something else.  NOT a problem with reading.  Did you really use `'file'` in the loadtxt call?

Comment: Based on the docs for ```numpy``` delimiter : str, optional "The string used to separate values. By default, this is any whitespace."  It appears it should not have any issues with your file, granted you are indeed importing the correct file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

Where `delim_whitespace=True` is your delimiter on the whitespace.

Alternatively, you could use

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('filet.txt')
```

where `read_fwf` stands for 'fixed width formatted lines'.  Again, I haven't tested, but I believe it should work.

Comment: That's great, thanks for the suggestions. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to do this easily with numpy?

Answer (score 2):

`loadtxt` shouldn't have problems with a file like that.  Simulating the read with a copy-n-paste of your print:

```
In [2]: txt = """   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+0
   ...: 0   0.0000000e+00   0.0000000e+00 
   ...:   -3.6344707e-03  -2.6598413e-02   8.4534688e-02  -8.6057356e-04   3.483
   ...: 3275e-04  -1.7481226e-05 
   ...:   -7.6545137e-03  -6.9117133e-02   1.0195991e-02  -1.1818548e-03   6.226
   ...: 1736e-04  -1.1414899e-04"""                                             
In [3]: np.loadtxt(txt.splitlines())                                            
Out[3]: 
array([[ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,
         0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00],
       [-3.6344707e-03, -2.6598413e-02,  8.4534688e-02, -8.6057356e-04,
         3.4833275e-04, -1.7481226e-05],
       [-7.6545137e-03, -6.9117133e-02,  1.0195991e-02, -1.1818548e-03,
         6.2261736e-04, -1.1414899e-04]])
```